# apend items in a dropdown list using another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, drop-down-menu

hey all i have a class Parent in which i have a drop down list (ddlNames) it contains some name

i have another class Relatives form this class i want to append some more names to ddlNames 
anyone suggest me ho can i do this

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Does your class inherit from Parent? You can just use `this.ddlNames.Add()`

Othewise, make sure ddlNames is public, and do `MyOtherClass.ddlNames.Add()`

Comment: i want to provide a function (defined in Parent class) that is called from the Relatives class to append names in the dropdownlist (ddlNames) & access the item selected event in the  Relatives class only

Comment: Then declare the method in your parent class and set it's scope to "private" - have this method accept a parameter to be added to your ddlNames property (make sure that's set to private, so can't be accessed outside the class).